# How to only load certain fields of a child object in Entity Framework 6.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I'm working on a model that has two classes, `Product` and `Transaction`.

```
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ProductId {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid TransactionId {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Customer { get; set; }
}
```

How do I do a query that will retrieve a product and the Date of its transactions? I tried something like

```
var product = db.Products.Include(p => p.Transactions.Select(t => new { t.Date })).Where(p => p.ProductId = productId);
```

But it throws an exception:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties

Edit for clarification:
What I want to achieve is actually *not* loading  `TransactionId` and `Customer` when `Transaction` is loaded.

Comment: You can't "not load" `TransactionId` and `Customer` because they were already loaded as they're not a navigation-properties. And even you were able to that, you'd gain no benefit from it...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To achieve what you need you don't have other choice than project your query to an anonymous type or a DTO. As you can see, in the [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method you can just specify the related entities you want to load which is translated in an inner join with a table (or several joins, see the *Remarks* section in the quoted link), but that doesn't mean you're going to load all the properties from the related entities. If you call the  `Select` method you can choose which columns you want to project, but you can't project a Linq to Entities query using an entity type, you must use one of the two options that I commented above. So, my advice is create in your business logic layer a set of classes (DTOs) to project the result of your queries, eg:

```
 public class ProductDTO
 {
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ProductId {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IEnumerable<DateTime> TransactionDates { get; set; }
 }
```

Later you can do something like this:

```
var product = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId = productId)
                         .Select(pr=> new ProductDTO
                         {
                           ProductId = pr.ProductId,
                           TransactionDates = pr.Transactions.Select(tr=>tr.Date),
                         }.ToList();
```

See I don't need to call `Include` extension method in this case, because in the `Select` I'm projecting a column from `Transactions` table. In that point the data is not still loaded, you are just defining a linq query that later is translated to sql. When that take place?, when you call `ToList` extension method.

As a last recommendation, I suggest you to take a look to [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). Once you have mapped your entities with their respective DTOs, your queries could be this way:

```
var product = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == productId)
                         .ProjectTo<ProductDTO>()    
                         .ToList();
```

More info about `ProjectTo` extension method in this [link](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions)

Answer (score 9):

you could also try [Anonymous projection](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx)

```
var product = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId = productId)
                         .Select(pr=> new 
                         {
                           product = pr,
                           transactionDates = pr.Transactions.Select(tr=>tr.Date),
                         }.ToList();
```

Comment: Each select results in additional brackets (list), is there any way to handle this? In your code there will be [ [ [ .. 3 brackets because there are 2 selects and then there is 1 ToList. Can you advise me how to remove those extra brackets?

Answer (score -1):

I think using a DTO is the best pattern. Anonymous projection works well if you're not returning the value.

Another option is to map to an anonymous type and then create the entity

```
public MyEntity Products => db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId = productId)
     .Select(pr=> new {
         product = pr,
         transactionDates = pr.Transactions.Select(tr=>tr.Date),
     }
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Select(e => new MyEntity { ... }); // Initialize a Linq entity here
```

Comment: What is "the entity"? `Product` already is an entity.

Comment: @GertArnold whichever entity that fits the bill, which one is irrelevant to the example. The problem is that LinqToQuery will complain if you instantiate an Entity in the query phase as a safe guard

Comment: Quite a hypothetical case then. If I want Customers, I get them from the database, not by  converting them from Products. I think the accepted answer already touches all relevant aspects. BTW, EF-core dropped the limitation you mention.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm not sure I'd say it's hypothetical. If you want a method to query the context without loading all fields from the database without using DTOs, this is how you'd do it. Still, I would strongly advise on using DTOs because this method really foregoes a lot of typesafety

Answer (score -2):

In addition to other answers, if you don't want to Reimplement the DTO class, you can do this:

```
public class ProductDTO : Product
{
}
```

So the DTO class will have the required fields and EF will not throw any exception.