# C# - EF Lambda Include for selecting 2 classes and excluding properties from the second class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to find a solution on how to avoid selecting other properties from my other class.

Suppose I have 2 classes with a name of Class1 and Class2 and I want to select only the Name1 in my Class2.

```
// My Models
public class Class1 {
    public int Class1Id {get;set;}
    public string Gender {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Class2> Class2 {get;set;}
}

public class Class2{
    public int Class2Id {get;set;}
    public string Name1 {get;set;}
    public string Name2 {get;set;}
    public string Name3 {get;set;}
    public string Name4 {get;set;}
    public string Name5 {get;set;}
    public string Name6 {get;set;}

    public int Class1Id {get;set;}
    public Class1 Class1 {get;set;}
}
```

I have a method that fetches all the records in Class1

```
public IQueryable<Class1> AllClass1(){
     return context.Class1.Include(c=>c.Class2);
}
```

This will work but the problem is, I only want to only select the Class2.Name1. Because in Include, it select other properties from Class2. Not only the Name1 but also the Name2-Name6.

This is for performance perspective and how fast the fetching of data.

Since, I won't need Name2-Name6, why would I choose to fetch them too?

Comment: juste use a DTO/ViewModel and projection through EF.

Comment: No. Because Class1 and Class2 has one-to-many relationship

Comment: Include is equivalent to Inner Join

Comment: That method AllClass1 is equivalent to select query

Comment: My comments wasn't a question :) I show you the only solution through what you can do to avoid retrieving columns you don't want.

Comment: did you downvote?

Comment: using ViewModel will not solve the main problem. I mean, public IQueryable<Class1> AllClass1() already fetching 2 classes. what if Class2 has a record of 30,000? Fetching from Name2-Name6 will fetch too slow. Even I only need Name1

Comment: It is not recommended to return an IQueryable (it violate the repository pattern when you're using this pattern). With IQueryable you're  loosing control about what the callers of your method are doing because they have total rights to do anything they want to do e.g. retrieving all data on you database.

Comment: But IQueryable is preferable than using IEnumerable when it comes to fetching records from database. as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select your property as a string array

```
context.Class1.Include(c => c.Class2).SelectMany(x => x.Class2).Select(x => x.Prop1)
```

If you want the Property in an array of the type of your class just create a new instance of it in the select method

```
context.Class1.Include(c=>c.Class2).SelectMany(x => x.Class2).Select(x => new Class2() { Prop1 = x.Prop1 })
```

And if you want the Class2 instance to be part of your Class1 you can do an Select on your Class1 but create an new instance of Class1 in the Select where you map every property of Class1 and set the Class2 array like in the code above

```
context.Class1.Include(c=>c.Class2).Select (x => new Class1() {
  Prop1 = x.Prop1,
  Prop2 = x.Prop2,
  ...
  Class2 = x.Class2.Select(y => new Class2() { Prop1 = y.Prop1 })
})
```

See also
[How to only load certain fields of a child object in Entity Framework 6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36765630/1216595)

Comment: But my IQueryable expects an return type of Class1 not a return type of Class2

Comment: As I mentioned, you can select your Class1 an create a new instance of Class1 in the select where you map every property + the Class2 array with only the single property loaded

Comment: I'm having an error and it says, Cannot implicitly type IEnumerable to ICollection. following your  third code snippet

Comment: Append .ToList() to make it an collection.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you sir. Now I have a faster fetching of records :)